# How to check if a node exists in CQ extjs?

Tags: extjs, aem

Is there a way to check if a node exist and then get the fetch the property value of it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `CQ.Util.eval` function and pass the node path followed by the `.json` extension as a single arugment:

```
var node = CQ.Util.eval('/content/geometrixx/en/jcr:content.json');
```

If the node doesn't exists you'll get `null`. Otherwise you can get properties using brackets:

```
if (node != null) {
    console.log(node['jcr:title']);
}
```